# select query -mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

If I have a table such as:

```
     name1       |    name2     |    id     |
+----------------+--------------+-----------+
| A              | E            | 1         |
| A              | F            | 1         |
| B              | G            | 1         |
| C              | H            | 1         |
| D              | I            | 1         |
| A              | J            | 2         |
| B              | K            | 2         |
| C              | L            | 2         |
| D              | M            | 2         |
| A              | N            | 2         |
```

what I need is that select all rows of id where name2 <> 'E'

If I do:

```
selete * from table where name2 <> 'E'
```

It only gives me this

```
     name1       |    name2     |    id     |
+----------------+--------------+-----------+
| A              | F            | 1         |
| B              | G            | 1         |
| C              | H            | 1         |
| D              | I            | 1         |
| A              | J            | 2         |
| B              | K            | 2         |
| C              | L            | 2         |
| D              | M            | 2         |
| A              | N            | 2         |
```

The result I want is (excluding all rows of id which contains name2 = 'E' at least once) :

```
     name1       |    name2     |    id     |
+----------------+--------------+-----------+
| A              | J            | 2         |
| B              | K            | 2         |
| C              | L            | 2         |
| D              | M            | 2         |
| A              | N            | 2         |
```

Which query should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to use subquery that finds all ids that have a value 'E' in column `name2` and then filter out all these ids:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE name2 = 'E' )
```

Comment: Note that if there's a row in the table that has an id value of NULL and name2 value of 'E', this query will return zero rows..

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM `table` WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE name2 <> 'E')

Answer (score 1):

We can use an anti-join pattern:

```
SELECT t.name1
     , t.name2
     , t.id
  FROM mytable t
  LEFT
  JOIN mytable q
    ON q.id    = t.id
   AND q.name2 = 'E'
 WHERE q.id IS NULL
```

The left outer join operation says to return all rows from `t`, along with matching rows from `q`. The trick is the condition in the WHERE clause. For any rows that found a matching row in `q`, the value of `q.id` is guaranteed to be non-NULL (because of the equality comparison). Rows from `t` that didn't have a matching row will have a NULL value for q.id.  So this returns only rows from `t` that didn't have a matching row from `q`.

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from table where name2 != 'E';
```